# Voice to text recognition using react not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, visual-web-developer

Here my code, anybody please help me how to use this js code in my react app i am new in react.
I try to use voice to text recognition in my react app.
And when i use this code with index.html file then it works well.
this is my app.js file, where i want to use my code of javascript.
I have no idea what i do next to solve this.

```
 import React from 'react';



    const About = () => {
    const $ = window.$;
    try {
    alert("hello");
      var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
      var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      $('.no-browser-support').show();
      $('.app').hide();
    }
      var noteTextarea = $('#note-textarea');
      var instructions = $('#recording-instructions');
      var notesList = $('ul#notes');

      var noteContent = '';

      // Get all notes from previous sessions and display them.
      var notes = getAllNotes();
      renderNotes(notes);



      /*-----------------------------
            Voice Recognition
      ------------------------------*/

      // If false, the recording will stop after a few seconds of silence.
      // When true, the silence period is longer (about 15 seconds),
      // allowing us to keep recording even when the user pauses.
      recognition.continuous = true;

      // This block is called every time the Speech APi captures a line.
      recognition.onresult = function(event) {

        // event is a SpeechRecognitionEvent object.
        // It holds all the lines we have captured so far.
        // We only need the current one.
        var current = event.resultIndex;

        // Get a transcript of what was said.
        var transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;

        // Add the current transcript to the contents of our Note.
        // There is a weird bug on mobile, where everything is repeated twice.
        // There is no official solution so far so we have to handle an edge case.
        var mobileRepeatBug = (current === 1 && transcript === event.results[0][0].transcript);

        if(!mobileRepeatBug) {
          noteContent += transcript;
          noteTextarea.val(noteContent);
        }
      };

      recognition.onstart = function() {
        instructions.text('Voice recognition activated. Try speaking into the microphone.');
      }

      recognition.onspeechend = function() {
        instructions.text('You were quiet for a while so voice recognition turned itself off.');
      }

      recognition.onerror = function(event) {
        if(event.error === 'no-speech') {
          instructions.text('No speech was detected. Try again.');
        };
      }



      /*-----------------------------
            App buttons and input
      ------------------------------*/

      $('#start-record-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        alert("hahna");

        if (noteContent.length) {
          noteContent += ' ';
        }
        recognition.start();
      });


      $('#pause-record-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        recognition.stop();
        instructions.text('Voice recognition paused.');
      });

      // Sync the text inside the text area with the noteContent variable.
      noteTextarea.on('input', function() {
        noteContent = $(this).val();
      })

      $('#save-note-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        recognition.stop();

        if(!noteContent.length) {
          instructions.text('Could not save empty note. Please add a message to your note.');
        }
        else {
          // Save note to localStorage.
          // The key is the dateTime with seconds, the value is the content of the note.
          saveNote(new Date().toLocaleString(), noteContent);

          // Reset variables and update UI.
          noteContent = '';
          renderNotes(getAllNotes());
          noteTextarea.val('');
          instructions.text('Note saved successfully.');
        }

      })


      notesList.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target);

        // Listen to the selected note.
        if(target.hasClass('listen-note')) {
          var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
          readOutLoud(content);
        }

        // Delete note.
        if(target.hasClass('delete-note')) {
          var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();
          deleteNote(dateTime);
          target.closest('.note').remove();
        }
      });



      /*-----------------------------
            Speech Synthesis
      ------------------------------*/

      function readOutLoud(message) {
        var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

        // Set the text and voice attributes.
        speech.text = message;
        speech.volume = 1;
        speech.rate = 1;
        speech.pitch = 1;

        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
      }



      /*-----------------------------
            Helper Functions
      ------------------------------*/

      function renderNotes(notes) {
        var html = '';
        if(notes.length) {
          notes.forEach(function(note) {
            html+= `<li class="note">
              <p class="header">
                <span class="date">${note.date}</span>
                <a href="#" class="listen-note" title="Listen to Note">Listen to Note</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete-note" title="Delete">Delete</a>
              </p>
              <p class="content">${note.content}</p>
            </li>`;
          });
        }
        else {
          html = '<li><p class="content">You don\'t have any notes yet.</p></li>';
        }
        notesList.html(html);
      }


      function saveNote(dateTime, content) {
        localStorage.setItem('note-' + dateTime, content);
      }


      function getAllNotes() {
        var notes = [];
        var key;
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
          key = localStorage.key(i);

          if(key.substring(0,5) === 'note-') {
            notes.push({
              date: key.replace('note-',''),
              content: localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))
            });
          }
        }
        return notes;
      }


      function deleteNote(dateTime) {
        localStorage.removeItem('note-' + dateTime);
      }

        return (
           <div>

           <div className="app">
               <h3>Add New Note</h3>
               <div className="input-single">
                   <textarea id="note-textarea" placeholder="Create a new note by typing or using voice recognition." rows="6"></textarea>
               </div>
               <button id="start-record-btn" title="Start Recording">Start Recognition</button>
               <button id="pause-record-btn" title="Pause Recording">Pause Recognition</button>
               <button id="save-note-btn" title="Save Note">Save Note</button>
               <p id="recording-instructions">Press the <strong>Start Recognition</strong> button and allow access.</p>

               <h3>My Notes</h3>
               <ul id="notes">
                   <li>
                       <p className="no-notes">You don't have any notes.</p>
                   </li>
               </ul>

           </div>


           </div>
        );
    }

    export default About;
```

Comment: What's not working? Could you please add more details...

Comment: when i click on start recognition the function is  not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`react-speech-recognition`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition) module to add the speech recognition functionality to your React project, It is the easier way to do this.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Dictaphone = () => {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition()

    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
            <p>{transcript}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Dictaphone
```